# How to import a multi-value dictionary in text file into python as a dictionary and what could go wrong. Need answer

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm new to programming.

I have a text file with a dictionary.

```
{1: [1, 6, 7, 15, 45, 55, 80], 2: [2, 5, 10, 27, 335], 3: [3, 21, 28, 32, 35], 4: [4, 39]}
```

I want to import this dictionary into my Jupyter notebook as a dictionary. I was able to import it but it came as a string.

```
'{1: [1, 6, 7, 15, 45, 55, 80], 2: [2, 5, 10, 27, 335], 3: [3, 21, 28, 32, 35], 4: [4, 39]}'
```

But I want it as a dictionary. What I'm doing wrong?
There were few sujestion and didn't work either of them.

One method sugest this

```
d = {}
with open("jdictText.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[int(key)] = val
        
d
# But I got this error
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-627c545e4457> in <module>
      2 with open("jdictText.txt") as f:
      3     for line in f:
----> 4        (key, val) = line.split()
      5        d[int(key)] = val
      6 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The other method with json got the error

```
import json
file_1 = open("jdictText.txt", 'r')
string = file_1.read()
d = json.loads(string)
d


JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-77dbdebba4e5> in <module>
      2 file_1 = open("jdictText.txt", 'r')
      3 string = file_1.read()
----> 4 d = json.loads(string)
      5 d

JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

sf

```
file_1 = open("jdictText.txt", 'r')
string = file_1.read()

#Now removing { and }
s = string.replace("{" ,"")
finalstring = s.replace("}" , "")

#Splitting the string based on , we get key value pairs
list = finalstring.split(",")

dictionary ={}
for i in list:
    #Get Key Value pairs separately to store in dictionary
    keyvalue = i.split(":")

    #Replacing the single quotes in the leading.
    m= keyvalue[0].strip('\'')
    m = m.replace("\"", "")
    dictionary[m] = keyvalue[1].strip('"\'')

print(dictionary)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-df2a2a3e5f37> in <module>
      7 
      8 print(string)
----> 9 print("Type: "+ type(string))

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "type") to str
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

file_1 = open("jdictText.txt", 'r')
string = file_1.read()
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval(string)
print(d)
type(d)


{'1': [1, 6, 7, 15, 45, 55, 80],
 '2': [2, 5, 10, 27, 335],
 '3': [3, 21, 28, 32, 35],
 '4': [4, 39]}

dict
```

Other method is You can save it as a Json file and import it as follows.

```
import json

with open('jdicJSON.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

print(d)    
type(d)


{'1': [1, 6, 7, 15, 45, 55, 80],
 '2': [2, 5, 10, 27, 335],
 '3': [3, 21, 28, 32, 35],
 '4': [4, 39]}
dict
```

Comment: You asked and answered your own question at the time of posting?